# What is the easiest way to print an array on rows?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] Test = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
}
```

I want to be able to print like this.

```
 1  2  3 
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

I have tried by using for loops three times to print it but i was wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: add a new line for each `index%3==0`?

Comment: @TheLostMind I think it should be `index%3==2` ? java array is 0-based.

Comment: @Kent - yes. This will add an additional new line at the beginning. This also depends on where you put the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**printf** could help.

This loop should do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s%s", Test[i], i % 3 == 2 ? "\n" : " ");
}
```

Comment: @user2775042 better follow the java naming convention. E.g. use `test` instead of `Test` as variable name

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < Test.length ; i++ ) {
    System.out.print(Test[i]+" ");
    if ( i%3 == 2 ) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < Test.length-2 ; i++ ) {
    System.out.print(Test[i]+" "+Test[i+1]+" "+Test[i+2]+"\n");
}
```

and change the name for `Test` in `test`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Test = new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
        for(int i = 1; i <= Test.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(Test[i - 1]+" ");
            if(i % 3 == 0)
               System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Kent maybe **completely wrong answer** is a bit too much. He is using the limits wrongly but that's all. All that you mention are caused by this. If you replace `Test[i]` with `Test[i-1]` it's fine (not the perfect answer but fine).

Comment: @Eypros ok.  reasonable, very likely he wanted to use `i-1` when he wrote the `for ...` but later, he forgot. I remove the comment (since I cannot edit it any longer), but still this is a **wrong** answer. with exception.

Answer (score 0):

For perfect alignment, you need to do two passes.  One to keep track of the maximum size of each to-be-printed column, and the second to print all the columns adjusted to the desired size.

This is because if you start printing the first line

```
1 2 3
```

some devious movement of the universe will eventually guarantee that the second row will contain the numbers

```
3425 2352342 2
```

and it will blow your alignment.  However, if you walk the data one time, updating the maximum size of the column (if necessary)

```
(row 1) (column 1 max size is 1) (column 2 max size is 1) (column 3 max size is 1)
(row 2) (column 1 max size is 4) (column 2 max size is 7) (column 3 max size is 1)
```

then the second time you go through the data, you can print each row with the correct amount of padding (spaces for max column width - width of data, and then the value)

```
   1       2 3
3425 2352342 2
```

Now as to how to transform a one dimensional array into a two dimensional array, it depends.  One could just declare a two dimensional array from the start, or you could specify the width of the row, counting off elements until a row is "filled".

Both techniques will work, and depending on circumstance, you might find that one approach fits some problems better than the other (but there's likely not a perfect solution for all problems).